# Nodejs json object one attribute value does not print while other does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `reservation` model in my database. This is how I fetch one entry (Using mongoose),

```
reservationModel.get_reservation_by_user_id(payload.user.id, function (err, reservations) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(reservations);
        console.log(reservations[0].user);  // prints undefined                         
        console.log(reservations[0].from); // prints 0900
      }
    });
```

Here is the console output.

```
Dialog Opened sucessful
[ { _id: 5a887a20734d1d041bb6a1f3,
    tutor: '5a760a1f734d1d3bd58c8d52',
    user: 'U8XDVJD26',
    date: 2018-02-17T13:53:45.415Z,
    day: 'Saturday',
    from: '0900',
    to: '1030',
    active: 'no' },
  { _id: 5a887bd2734d1d041bb6a24f,
    tutor: '5a760a1f734d1d3bd58c8e12',
    user: 'U8XDVJD26',
    date: 2018-02-17T14:00:45.415Z,
    day: 'Saturday',
    from: '0930',
    to: '1130',
    active: 'no' } ]
undefined
0900
```

How can I get the value of user?

Comment: no problem in the given code

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema definition for `reservationModel`? Most probably you haven't added the field in the schema definition.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had written user_id instead of user in my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 'user_id' written in my schema and not 'user', this was the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a record by id you need to use a method `findById`. Example:

```
reservationModel.findById(payload.user.id, function (err, reservations) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(reservations);
        console.log(reservations.user);                     
        console.log(reservations.from);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I have written a logic to find reservation in my own function `get_reservation_by_user_id` and when I log the response it shows fine as I displayed that in the output as well. So I dont think the problem is with the method call.

Comment: I understood you. Sorry for wrong answer.